# PoW Rewards for Mining

Tags: consensus, validator, substrate-recipes

In [this](https://substrate.recipes/basic-pow.html) Substrate Recipe it says nothing about the rewards miners get for including blocks into the chain in the PoW consensus.
But I found that Kulupu uses a [rewards](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/tree/master/frame/rewards) pallet which, at first glance, manages the rewards for the miners.
The questions are:

- Is it necessary to implement a similar pallet to give miners rewards? Will the PoW chain reach consensus and function normally (produce blocks) without it? (as per recipe)
- Are there any other (maybe Parity's) implementations of such reward mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to implement a pallet if you want to issue rewards, but it isn't required for PoW chain as such to operate.

The pallet Kulupu uses isn't very minimal, something simpler like what [we used in Subspace](https://github.com/subspace/subspace/blob/3f4c8367c86f9851ef2ebb8b12b098d31a0df5b3/crates/pallet-rewards/src/lib.rs) can already be sufficient depending on the use case.